# QGIS DXF points to raster

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have a dxf file that contains points with heights. When I import into a QGIS dxf file I don't see the elevation in the open attribute table. My goal is to get a raster from that dxf.

[image]

However, after that I came up with the idea to add those values with the field calculator. but I don't know what the next step is. I need a raster for the entire TIN and not just for individual points.

Do you know the steps?